# Codeigniter doesn't load the view

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter but for some reason I can't get it working. What I am trying to do is very simple. I have a `post.php` file inside `controller` folder. Contents of `post.php` is as following:

```
    class Posts extends CI_Controller{
        function index(){
            $this->load->view('hello.php');
        }
    }
```

Then my `hello.php` file is inside `views` folder. It is just a static HTML page. Just trying to get it working first.

The folder structure is a follows: `htdocs/codeignitor`

I was expecting to get contents of hello.php when I visit:

```
http://localhost:8888/codeigniter/index.php/posts
```

When I visit the above url it says **`Page Not Found`**. But the default welcome page is working fine.

Comment: Did you try renaming the file to `posts.php`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$this->load->view('hello');
```

Your files should be placed as follows:

```
htdocs
|
+-- codeignter
    |
    +-- application
        |
        +-- controllers
        |  |
        |  +-- posts.php
        +-- views
           |
           +-- hello.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't add the '.php' extension.  Like this:

$this->load->view('hello');

Answer (score 1):

Never use 'file extents' while using for loading:
you suggetsed to use:

```
$this->load->view('hello');
```

that's it;

Answer (score 0):

plz check the file-name
 it should be `posts.php` if ur class name is `Posts`
and if this is correct then check the `config.php` for the `$config['base_url']` and set ur site url properly.